# How to set a fixed length to a string in python in a similar fashion as the setLength attribute java

Tags: java, python, string

I have a scenario in python where I need to ensure a variable is set to a specific length.  It can't be over or under x characters. If the variable is smaller, I need \u0000 spaces appended to the end of the line (similar to how java performs the task).

Java has an attribute within their [StringBuffer class called setLength](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) that allows one to set a fixed length to a variable.  I created a function for my use, but want to do this using standard python libraries.

Is there a comparable function available in python?

```py
'''
' The setLength function will set the length of a string.  
' This is similar to the setLength attribute in java
' The end of the string should be padded with \u0000
'''
def setLength(sVal,length=0):
    sLength = len(sVal)
    if sLength > length:
        sVal = sVal[:length-sLength]
    elif sLength < length:
        thePadding = length - sLength
        theBuffer = "".join(['\u0000' for x in range(thePadding)])
        sVal = sVal+theBuffer
    return sVal

exampleA=setLength('I love it dude!',15)
print(exampleA)
exampleB=setLength('I love it!',15)
print(exampleB)
exampleC=setLength('I love it dude! How can we add more to this string?',15)
print(exampleC)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily write one:

```
padding_char = '*'

def setLength(s, max_length):
    return (s + padding_char * max_length) [:max_length]

exampleA=setLength('I love it dude!',15)
print(exampleA)
exampleB=setLength('I love it!',15)
print(exampleB)
exampleC=setLength('I love it dude! How can we add more to this string?',15)
print(exampleC)
```

prints :

```
I love it dude!
I love it!*****
I love it dude!
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) might be an option:

```
'{0:\u0000<15.15}'.format('I love it dude!')
```

where `\u0000` is the character to fill up to the minimum length, `<` is the alignment of the text (in this case left), the first `15` the minimum length, the second `15` the maximum length.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ljust` to pad extra characters.

```py
def setLength(s, width):
    if len(s) < width:
        return s.ljust(width - len(s), '\u0000')
    else:
        return s[:width]
```